# `FOREIGN KEY` on PlanetScale

Tags: python-3.x, django, planetscale

I want to deploy a Django app on Vercel which uses PlanetScale as database. But since PlanetScale does not support foreign key and the Django works heavily with this constraint. So my question is there is any way that solves this problem ?

I tried `db_contraint` setting to `False` like `models.ForeignKey(Buses, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_constraint=False)` this for my models but this also not working.

Answer (score 0):

I found a GitHub repository called [django_psdb_engine](https://github.com/planetscale/django_psdb_engine), which offers a custom database engine for Django. This engine subclasses the existing `django.db.backends.mysql` engine and disables foreign key constraints, allowing you to run Django migrations without any problems. I've attached the link for your reference.

As the document says

1. In the root of your project:

```bash
git clone https://github.com/planetscale/django_psdb_engine.git
```

2. In your `settings.py` file, find the `DATABASES` object and modify the `ENGINE` field as follows:

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_psdb_engine',
    }
}
```

3. Run migrations with:

```bash
python manage.py migrate
```